# What are surface elements?

Tags: vector-analysis

would somebody please help me out with surface integrating? While calculating flux, there is the integrand $F\cdot n$ however in the definition of surface integration I am reading about $|| r_{u} \times r_{v}||$. Thanks very much. I do not remember why I keep having to change $d\mathbf{S}$ into $\mathbf{n} dS$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say $d\mathbf{S}$ is the vector element of surface area and $dS$ is the scalar element of surface area.  So $d\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{N} dS$ where $\mathbf N$ is the unit normal to the surface.

Which normal?  The one chosen according to the rules you are using!  Technically, you are integrating over an oriented surface, and $\mathbf{N}$ is determined by the orientation.

---

**added**
Note if $\mathbf r(u,v)$ is a parametric description of the surface, then at each point of the surface, $\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}$ are tangents to the surface, 
$\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}$ is a normal to the surface.  The norm $\|\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}\|$ is the length of that normal vector.  Then think of $dS = \|\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}\|\;du\;dv$, where $\|\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}\|$ is the area of a paralellogram with sides $\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v}$.  And $d\mathbf S = (\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial v})\;du\;dv$ is a vector with magnitude $dS$ and perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: I could not see why the to multiply by the magnitude $\displaystyle || \dfrac{dx}{du} \times \dfrac{dx}{dv}||$....

Comment: unless they are just analogs to the multiplication as in spherical and cylindrical coordinates, etc.